# how to set a login page as landing page, and then redirect to a vuejs component in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm working on a web application using laravel with vuejs, and I would like to set the login page as a landing page, if not logged in, and redirect to the home page if logged in.

I tried using the following code, but it only works if the page is defined as a blade.php file, in my case i need a component.vue file as a homepage.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you register your component in you app.js you can use it on the page.

Place this after the window.Vue declaration in your app.js and before new Vue

```
Vue.component('home-component', require('./components/HomeComponent.vue').default);
```

After that your can use
    `<home-component></home-component>` inside your blade.

If you only want to have this when a user is logged in place it inside an if tag

```
@if(Auth::user())
   <home-component></home-component>
@endif
```